# Is there a book that gathers together all the Hadiths accepted by both Sunni and Shia sources?

Tags: hadith, sunni, authenticity, shiism, uloom-al-hadith

I know there are many differences in Hadith accepted by either Sunni and Shia Muslims.  However I was curious if anyone has ever gathered together Hadith which both groups accept in each of their respective collections.